# Finding limit with improper integral

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

How should I approach this question?
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}\int_1^{1+x}\frac{\cos t}{t} \, dt$$
I tried to use L'hospital and that gave me $-\sin(0) = 0$

The correct answer is $\cos 1$. Did I L'hospital wrong or is that the wrong way to go?

Comment: The integral is not improper!!

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $$F(x) = \int_{1}^{x}\frac{\cos t}{t}\,dt.$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus we have $F'(x)=\frac{\cos x}{x}$, and we want to compute:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F(x+1)-F(1)}{x} \stackrel{DH}{=}\lim_{x\to 0}f(x+1) = f(1) = \cos(1).$$

Answer (score 0):

L'Hospital's Rule works fine here.  Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_1^{1+x} \frac{\cos(t)}{t}\,dt}{x}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^{1+x} \frac{\cos(t)}{t}\,dt}{\frac{dx}{dx}}\\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\cos(1+x)}{1+x}}{1}\\\\
&=\cos(1)
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. If the answer is not useful, I am happy to delete. Please advise. -Mark